# How to write the Python code for calculating numbers with alphabet characters

Tags: python, math, calculator, sympy

I Want to create python calculator solve 2a+3a , 3ab+5ab like questions. I did normal calculator but I want to create this type of calculator. How to do it? Give me some idea

Comment: Look how to properly ask a question on stackoverflow. This question will probably be closed as its poor.

Comment: I don't know how to ask question can u teach me?

Comment: Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And do you mean to *evaluate* your *expressions* or did you mean *solve* some *equations* you did not show?

Comment: thanks i will check it sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Please add your deleted answer inside the question (or the parts of the answer that would make your question more clear). It was deleted since it was not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you get input,

```
import re
s = "2a + 3b+ 4a +3bc"
input = [x.strip() for x in s.split('+')]

var_dict = {}
for inp in input:
    variable = ''.join(x for x in inp if x.isalpha())
    var_dict.setdefault(variable, []).append(int(re.search(r'\d+', inp).group()))

fin_str = []
for key,val in var_dict.iteritems():
    fin_str.append(str(sum(val)) + str(key))

puts ', '.join([str(x) for x in fin_str])
```

python version 2.7+

Comment: This Code Working Only Sum How to Solve the Subtract ? for an example 3a+2a-2a like questions